# How to setInterval() in Electron BrowserWindow?

Tags: electron

I have a simple Electron application that queries a SQL database and displays the output via an HTML table. I have everything working correctly, but now I need to "refresh" the HTML table every X minutes (with the new results of the SQL query).

Right now, I have it working correctly using the meta tag directly in the HTML with: http-equiv="refresh" content="300". This correctly refreshes the page every 5 minutes, which is exactly what I want.

Although, the problem is that the refresh causes the screen to go white while the SQL query executes and the HTML is built. Obviously, the better solution would be to use the DOM and only modify the cells that have actually changed, since the last refresh. The problem I am running into, is getting "setInterval" to work correctly.... Once again, this is a VERY SIMPLE electron application. I am using their starting boiler plate. I have tried adding the "setInterval" in the `<body>` tag, using code like this:

```
<body onload='setInterval(updateTable(), 300000);'>
```

but the code only fires once... I have also tried adding the following code at the end of the body (just inside the `</body>` tag):

```
<script>
    window.onload=function(e){
        setInterval(updateTable(), 300000);
    }
</script>
```

...removing it from the window.onload handler...:

```
<script>
    setInterval(updateTable(), 300000);
</script>
```

...and also by moving it to the "renderer.js" file:

```
setInterval(updateTable(), 300000);
```

in all cases, it only fires once...I know this because the first line of code in updateTable() outputs the current date and time to the console, via console.log()..

I have tried lowering the timeout value to 10 seconds (from 300000 to 10000), just so I don't have to wait so long while testing and that didn't make any difference. I suspect the problem I am having has something to do with my lack of knowledge of the electron framework (like, perhaps the different "processes") and I have been searching for solutions for two days now, with no luck. Any advice on how I can accomplish this, is MUCH APPRECIATED!

Comment: Hi Shayne, have you tried moving the `setInterval` outside of the `window.onload` function? It shouldn't make a difference but who knows :). Other than that can you include how you're checking that it only fires once? E.g. with a `console.log` inside the `updateTable` function.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Yes, I have. See the edits I made to the main page...

Comment: Do you still have the `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="300"` in your page? If so it could be worth deleting it. Can you also include your entire `renderer.js` file? Or if too big just the relevant parts.

Comment: Yes, I removed the refresh meta tag (otherwise, it would actually be refreshing). The "renderer.js" file is empty other than the default comments. As I mentioned, this is a very simple app.

Comment: Have you tried moving the entire `updateTable` function inside the `setInterval`? E.g. `setInterval(function () { Update table code goes here }, 10000);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### TL;DR

Your issue has nothing to do with Electron and more with what exactly you pass to `setInterval`. You're not passing the function `updateTable`, but the result of the function call `updateTable()`. Remove the parentheses after the function name.

### Analysis

Both functions `setInterval` and `setTimeout` expect a *function* as their first parameter, which they will call at a specific time or regularly. What you pass to `setInterval` is, however, not a function. You write:

```
setInterval(updateTable(), 10000)
```

When this line is executed, `updateTable` is called and its *return value* is passed to `setInterval`. (If the function doesn't explicitly return anything, it returns `undefined`.) That's why your function is just called a single time (when setting up the timer).

If you write

```
setInterval(updateTable, 10000) // no parentheses
```

you're actually passing the function to `setInterval`, which will then run it repeatedly.

You may wonder why your workaround using `setTimeout` works. This is because you actually pass a function to it. You're specifying the function inline, but don't call it at that time. It does not matter that *inside* that function, you make the call to `updateTable`. What matters is what you pass to the timer functions.

Comment: Wow... "forest for the trees", anyone? Thanks snwflk! Another reason I was overlooking that syntax, is because I am actually passing two arguments to "updateTable". I switched back to setInterval, using: `setInterval('updateTable("tableOutput")', 10000)` but it should be noted that the function (with arguments) can also be passed using an anonymous function or an arrow function. (Depending on your version, of course.)

Comment: Actually.... to avoid the "eval", I ended up switching to an arrow function with: `setInterval( () => { updateTable("tableOutput"); },1000);`

Answer (score -1):

I have found a fix/workaround... either there is a "bug" with setInterval or (most likely) I am just missing something due to my "newness" to the frakework. But, instead of using setInterval, I switched to setTimeout, then in the callback, after calling updateTable(), I just set another setTimeout. For whatever reason, this works perfectly.... basically, in "renderer.js", I replaced:

```
setInterval(updateTable(), 10000);
```

with

```
let timer = setTimeout(function refreshTimer() {
    updateTable();
    timer = setTimeout(refreshTimer, 10000);
  }, 10000);
```

Even though these are functionally equivalent, for some reason it now works perfectly.